# Accordion bullet list non-jquery back end possible or CSS?

Tags: asp.net, accordion

I have a Accordion that's populating links via the back end, however, I would like these listed Bulleted.  Is there a way without using jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ContentContainer.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("&bull; "));
```

This is the C# behind code way